# C++ : how to change a member function at runtime (inside a shared library)?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I have a class DoorTerminal with a member function getInput() as shown below.

```
DoorTerminal::DoorTerminal(DialogueBox *dialogue_, Door* door_): DialogueInterfacing(dialogue_){
  emptyFor.push_back(string("Player"));
  type.push_back(string("DoorTerminal"));
  type.push_back(string("DialogueInterfacing"));
  imgpath = "/vagrant_data/Skeleton-game/src/sprites/terminal.png";
  typestring = "DoorTerminal";
  door = door_;
}
void DoorTerminal::getInput(){
  string input = dialogue->getInput();
  if(input == "1234"){
      door->unlock();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create an instance of this class inside a function defined in a .so shared library and change the getInput function pointer to instead point to a different function at runtime, like so

```
void getInput2(){
          string input = "EE";
          if(input == "1234"){
             cout << "hello" << endl;
             }
    }

    DoorTerminal* doorTerminal = new DoorTerminal(Door* door);
    doorTerminal->getInput = getInput2;
```

which results in an "invalid use of member function" error.
I've also experimented with std::function for the same purpose but so far with no luck.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can't do that - C++ is not Python. If you want something modifiable, you need to make it a member variable instead of a function. (But it's most likely a sign that a redesign would be in order.)

Comment: You can use a `std::function` but you can't make `DoorTerminal::getInput()` point to some different function.

Comment: What exactly was wrong with `std::function`? Also, if not `std::function`, just make `getInput` a virtual function, and write a factory method to create different kinds of `DoorTerminal`.